# Terminal Broken | rbenv: command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I am having a bad experience with the Terminal on OS X Mavericks. I was updating Ruby on OS X when I started encountering this error when starting the Terminal

```
-bash: rbenv: command not found
```

When I try `brew doctor`

```
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:104:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:104:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

My Paths File

```
/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/local/bin
~/.bash_profile
```

When I quit completely out of the Terminal and run it again I get it working but with errors

```
-bash: eval: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
-bash: eval: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
-bash: rbenv: command not found
```

Running

```
    $ brew doctor
    Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
    formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
    Consider setting the PATH for example like so
        echo export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: So to fix the homebrew issue I added "/usr/local/sbin" to my PATHS file.